# Products not being added to cart

Tags: php, html

Am having issues with my cart script, i've managed to get it to work by adding an item to the cart, but its not allowing any more items to be added but rather it allows the quantity to be added even when i add another item, its the quantity of the first item that will be increased, here is my code snippet

This my function script that wrietes and generates the cart

```
 <?php

function writeShoppingCart() {
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (!$cart) {
        return '<p>You have no items in your shopping cart</p>';
    } else {
        // Parse the cart session variable
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $s = (count($items) > 1) ? 's':'';
        return '<p>You have <a href="cart.php">'.count($items).' item'.$s.' in your shopping cart</a></p>';
    }
}

function showCart() {
    $currency = 'UGX';
    global $db;
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if ($cart) {
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $contents = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
        }
        $output[] = '<form action="cart.php?action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
        $output[] = '<table class="table table-striped">';
        foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '.$id;
            $result = $db->query($sql);
            $row = $result->fetch();
            extract($row);
            $output[] = '<tr>';
            $output[] = '<td><a href="cart.php?action=delete&id='.$id.'" class="r">Remove</a></td>';
            $output[] = '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
            $output[] = '<td>'.$currency.''.$product_price.'</td>';
            $output[] = '<td><input type="text" name="qty'.$id.'" value="'.$qty.'" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>';
            $output[] = '<td>'.$currency.''.($product_price  * $qty).'</td>';
            $total += $product_price * $qty;
            $output[] = '</tr>';
        }
        $output[] = '</table>';
        $output[] = '<p>Grand total: <strong>'.$currency.''.$total.'</strong></p>';
        $output[] = '<div><button type="submit">Update cart</button></div>';
        $output[] = '</form>';
    } else {
        $output[] = '<p>You shopping cart is empty.</p>';
    }
    return join('',$output);
}

?>
```

This is my cart script that handles actions from the cart buttons(add, delete and update)

```
<?php
    session_start();
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$action = $_GET['action'];
switch ($action) {
    case 'add':
        if ($cart) {
            $cart .= ','.!isset($_GET['product_id']);
        } else {
            $cart = !isset($_GET['product_id']);
        }
        break;
    case 'delete':
        if ($cart) {
            $items = explode(',',$cart);
            $newcart = '';
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if (!isset($_GET['product_id']) != $item) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$item;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
            $cart = $newcart;
        }
        break;
    case 'update':
    if ($cart) {
        $newcart = '';
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if (stristr($key,'qty')) {
                $id = str_replace('qty','',$key);
                $items = ($newcart != '') ? explode(',',$newcart) : explode(',',$cart);
                $newcart = '';
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    if ($id != $item) {
                        if ($newcart != '') {
                            $newcart .= ','.$item;
                        } else {
                            $newcart = $item;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for ($i=1;$i<=$value;$i++) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$id;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $cart = $newcart;
    break;
}
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
?>
```

And this is how send actions to my cart from the add button

```
<form action="cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row_prdt_details['product_id']; ?>" method="post" id="cart">
                        <fieldset>
                        <address>
                                <strong>Name:</strong> <span><?php echo $row_prdt_details['product_name']; ?></span><br>
                                <strong>Cake Code:</strong> <span><?php echo $row_prdt_details['product_id']; ?></span><br>
                                <strong>Availability:</strong> <span>
                                                                    </span><br>                             
                            </address>                                  
                            <h4><strong>Price: UGX <?php echo $row_prdt_details['product_price']; ?></strong></h4>              
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                <label>Qty:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="span1" name="qty" placeholder="1">
                                <input type="submit" onClick="window.location.reload()" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
```

All i want to achieve is to be able to add more items
Any help is greatly welcomed, if u have any questions about what am doing please ask me

Comment: Sidenote: `session_start();` must be inside ALL files using sessions. I didn't see it inside your first body of code.

Comment: when i add session_start(); in all files, i get a notice; PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: There's a lot of code here. You can't narrow it down any further than this?

Comment: You really don't have a choice since you're using sessions in that page. A quick possible fix is to put `ob_start();` above `session_start();` which may work, however by what you've told me, you have output above that, either being HTML, more PHP, a space, cookie, even a byte order mark; could be anything. So, that could be the issue here, or "an" issue.

Comment: @JohnConde i thout of it being a good idea to post allmost all the code since i've failed to find a solution what am doing......

Comment: @Fred-ii- ob_start(); is not solving anything, scenario is, i am able to add atleast one item to my cart but i can't add any atha, if i add anatha item, the quantity for first item will be increased but the item its self is not added